# How do you enable file specific tab indent settings in VIM?

Tags: vim, configuration, indentation, auto-indent

I believe there is a method to write a comment in a file that vim will use to override default tabbing and indent values.

Can someone point me to information about this feature and how to use it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per-file settings can be done using "[modeline magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic)".

The basic idea is that you can add a comment to an individual file like this:

```
/* vim: set tabstop=8:softtabstop=8:shiftwidth=8:noexpandtab */
```

Within vim, you should review:

- [:help auto-setting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#auto-setting)
- [:help modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modeline%27)
- [:help modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modelines%27)

Comment: thanks ... only leaving the */ on the same line gives me "E518: Unknown option: */"

Comment: Or you could just use a single-line comment!

Comment: Also not that vim will read vi modelines (good if you're changing vi compatible settings, not so useful for softtabstop etc.), and the abbreviated names work also, so you could have `/* vim: se ts=8:sts=8:sw=8:noet */`